# Android surface canvas.drawRect has a decaying shadow effect

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I'm writing an Android app which uses custom draw on SurfaceView and I'm getting a decaying shadow effect when i move the object (currently a `rect`). Below is portion of my code.

```
    canvas = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
    if (canvas != null) {
        synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
        // Starts of actual drawing code
            if (paintFg != null) {
                canvas.drawARGB(55, 55, 55, 55);
                canvas.drawRect(x, y, x+100, y+100, paintFg);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I change x and y, the box is drawn elsewhere, but the existing place have a decaying effect. I would like disable that.

Btw, I'm testing this on a Galaxy S3 with JellyBean. Not sure if ProjectButter that causes this, and I've get to tried on a older phone.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if I change `canvas.drawARGB(55, 55, 55, 55);` to `canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);` it solved the problem. But I'm still not sure what's the cause. Anyone care to point out?